# Is it possible to catch the command not found error?

Tags: bash, shell, posix

So, if you're on Posix, and you type something that isn't a command, it gives you a "command not found" error.

```
> ggg
-bash: ggg: command not found
```

Is there a way to intercept this and have it trigger a different command? What about changing the text.

(I am using a Mac… if that matters, but I also use Ubuntu and varieties of RHEL)

Comment: Have a look on this post too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104579/catch-command-not-found-from-shell-script

Comment: @Facebook That looks like a great answer. Almost "this should be marked duplicate" level.

Comment: If it's not on SuperUser it is not duplicate so leave for now until others see and chime in.

Comment: What do you think about the double pipe method from the other answer? Maybe that and have command 2 or the error command grep to find a specific string and only run another command if that string (e.g. "`command not found`") value is true?

Answer (score 0):

Bash doesn't have a Try/Catch/Except, but you can use || like this. If the second command will only run, if the first one fails. Thats what the double pipe is doing here. And thats for any kind of error.

`gggg || gggg2`

where gggg2 is your other command

Comment: So with this solution he could potentially run `<command 1> || <error command>` with all applicable commands and that would ensure that the error command is only run in the event that the first command fails.